# Computing $U \times V \times W$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, vectors

Problem:

Given the vectors:
\begin{align*}
U &= ( 3,2,-1 ) \\
V &= ( 0, 2, -3 ) \\
W &= ( 2,6,7 ) \\
\end{align*}
What is wrong with the expression: $U \times V \times W$?

Answer:
My answer is nothing but I am assuming that the cross product operator is
left associative. That is, $UxVxW$ means $(UxV)xW$. I need to make
this assumption because the cross product operator is not commutative. I am
now going to find $UxVxW$.
\begin{align*}
UxV &= \begin{vmatrix}
i & j & k \\
3 & 2 & -1 \\
0 & 2 & -3 \\
\end{vmatrix} \\
UxV &= i \begin{vmatrix}
2 & -1 \\
2 & -3 \\
\end{vmatrix}
-j  \begin{vmatrix}
3 & -1 \\
0 & -3 \\
\end{vmatrix}
+ k \begin{vmatrix}
3 & 2 \\
0 & 2 \\
\end{vmatrix} \\
UxV &= (-6+2)i - j(-9) + k(6) \\
UxV &= -4i + 9j + 6k \\
UxVxW &=\begin{vmatrix}
i & j & k \\
-4 & 9 & 6 \\
2 & 6 & 7 \\
\end{vmatrix} \\
UxVxW &= i \begin{vmatrix}
9 & 6 \\
6 & 7 \\
\end{vmatrix} 
-j \begin{vmatrix}
-4 & 6 \\
2 & 7 \\
\end{vmatrix} +
k \begin{vmatrix}
-4 & 9 \\
2 & 6 \\
\end{vmatrix} \\
UxVxW &= i (63-36) - j(-28-12) + k(-24-18) \\
UxVxW &= 27i + 40k - 42k \\
\end{align*}
Seems like there is no issue to me. Is the question a botch?

Comment: Please use `\times` for cross product. But yes, it would help to specify the bracketing for cross product. Otherwise you get $(-2,-20,-46)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cross product is not associative. On the one hand you have
$$\left(
\left(
\begin{matrix}
3 \\ 
2 \\
-1
\end{matrix}
\right) 
\times
\left(
\begin{matrix}
0 \\
2 \\
-3
\end{matrix}
\right)\right) \times
\left(
\begin{matrix}
2 \\
6 \\
7
\end{matrix}
\right) 
= 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
-4 \\
9 \\
6
\end{matrix}
\right) 
\times 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
2 \\
6 \\
7
\end{matrix}
\right) 
= 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
27 \\
40 \\
-42
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
and on the other hand (you should double check my computations)
$$
\left(
\begin{matrix}
3 \\ 
2 \\
-1
\end{matrix}
\right) 
\times
\left(
\left(
\begin{matrix}
0 \\
2 \\
-3
\end{matrix}
\right) \times
\left(
\begin{matrix}
2 \\
6 \\
7
\end{matrix}
\right)
\right) = 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
3 \\
2 \\
-1
\end{matrix}
\right) 
\times
\left(
\begin{matrix}
32 \\
-6 \\
-4
\end{matrix}
\right)=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
-14 \\
-20 \\
-82
\end{matrix}
\right).
$$
So you cannot drop the brackets in the expressions $(U \times V) \times W$ or $U \times (V \times W)$.